# sort by date is not working in edge

Tags: javascript, sorting, angular, microsoft-edge

I am trying to sort a array object by date

```
this.result.sort((a, b) => {
if (this.filter.orderBy === 'possession') {
  //if(moment(a.overview.possession_starts).isAfter(moment(b.overview.possession_starts))) 
  //sort string ascending
  if (moment(a.overview.possession_starts) > moment(b.overview.possession_starts)) 
     //sort string ascending
     return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

is working fine in Mozilla and chrome

Comment: no of iteration is alos diff in edge and chrome

Comment: You never return a negative value ? The bug isn't in Edge but in your code

Comment: Please show us a functioning reproduction. You can stand up an example in your question by [creating a snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 1):

Your callback returns `1`, `0` or `undefined`. This isn't what's required by the [sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Fix it:

```
if (this.filter.orderBy === 'possession') {
    this.result.sort((a, b) => {
           return moment(a.overview.possession_starts).milliseconds() - moment(b.overview.possession_starts).milliseconds();
    });
}
```

Comment: I guess you want to sort by `.valueOf()`(milliseconds since 1970) not by `.milliseconds()` (milliseconds since last second)